# Work leave planner Web Application

Tags: django, web, calendar, .net-core

Recently I've been assigned a task to develop a web app to plan leaves at our company. The main functionality is selecting days that given employee wants to reserve and then accepting/declining by those dates by his manager. Also, employees will be paired, so one of pair has to always be at work.

I have zero experience in developing web applications, so I need some help. Do you have any tips? Or maybe do you know of any existing project that are similar? I wanted to use Django, but any technology will do.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do have experience in Python?

Comment: There are plenty of python django tutorials out there. I suggest getting yourself familiarized with django before you go straight to developing a full fledged deploy ableapp with it. Which can probably take months to do.

Comment: Yes, i have some experience in python, I also went through few tutorials about Django. I just need some familiar projects to see how people solved these problems